# A verb for "going back in history"?

Tags: word-choice

> **Let's go back in time about one century** to see how people were thinking about this problem then.
>
> **Let's go about one century back in time** to see how people were thinking about this problem then.
>
> **Let's time-travel about one century back in history** to see how people were thinking about this problem then.

Which way of saying the bold part is more idomatic? Or maybe there is better suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, it would be "going back in history", not "going back in *the* history", because we're talking about history as a general concept, and "*the* history" implies one specific story about something.  You would only use the definite article if you wanted to indicate something specific like "the history of the steel industry".

Answer (score 3):

***[“Step back (in time)”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/step-back-in-time)*** is an idiomatic expression you may use in your sentences: 
​

> to go back into the past:
>
> - Visiting her house was like stepping back in time/stepping back 50 years.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

You may use  “go back in time” as well.

Answer (score 1):

"In time" or "in history" are not needed, since "time" is implied by "one century". So

> Let's go back one century to see ...

or you can drop the time travel metaphor and say

> Let's see how people were thinking about this problem one century ago.

Comment: so "go back" is idiomatic when we are talking about time?

Comment: I find it quite natural to hear "go back in time about one century." In fact, I'd say it sounds more natural (barring other context) than leaving any of its components out.